# Sitecore/Virtualuser updates and resets value on a page that has not been updated recently

Tags: cms-only, virtual-user

We have an item which has rendering parameter set on a rendering in Presentation details. Recently we noticed that this rendering parameter values has been reset. We have not recently updated the page.

When we analyzed this further we found that this occurred in both QA and PROD environments. And the page got edited by **sitecore/virtualssuser**
[image]

The Web DB has the correct values.

Master DB is missing the values on all versions of the item.

We investigated the logs further and found,

> INFO  [Content Testing]: PhantomJS console:  Resource error id: 1 url:
> [http://cms.com/?sc_mode=edit&sc_itemid={E842E945-991B-4DA5-A961-CAA3DEA4142A}&sc_disable_edit=yes&sc_lang=en&sc_version=13&sc_vercomp=25&sc_device={FE5D7FDF-89C0-4D99-9AA3-B5FBD009C9F3}](http://cms.com/?sc_mode=edit&sc_itemid=%7BE842E945-991B-4DA5-A961-CAA3DEA4142A%7D&sc_disable_edit=yes&sc_lang=en&sc_version=13&sc_vercomp=25&sc_device=%7BFE5D7FDF-89C0-4D99-9AA3-B5FBD009C9F3%7D)
> errorCode: 5 errorString: Operation canceled !--error--!

Not sure how this item got updated and how rendering parameters got reset. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Can you please share some screenshots or add more details on it?

Comment: What is your question? This is not clear to me.

Comment: @SumitBhatia , Richard I have updated my question.